# Nodejs search and paginate returned results

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, pagination, ejs

I need help or advice on how to manage this. I'm working on a node / mysql project. I need to paginate my data which I've managed to implement successfully. Now I only have one problem that has taken me over two days trying to solve to no avail. When a user searches in my site and let's assume the search results is over 100 records, I need to paginate these results on the frontend. Now the issue is,how do I maintain the search query when the user clicks on page 2 or 3. The situation at the moment is when the user searches the first page record is returned successfully and well paginated but when he clicks on page 2 the search query ain't there anymore. so am trying to figure out how to maintain this query search in my app so that when he searches for 1000 records they're able to be paginated and he maeuvres through each page containing the search results successfully.

this is my backend pagination code at the moment with the  pagination  and my frontend template is ejs

```
app.get('/jobs', (req, res) => {       
    
    db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        const numOfResults = result.length;
        const numberOfPages = Math.ceil(numOfResults / resultsPerPage);
        let page = req.query.page ? Number(req.query.page) : 1;
        if(page > numberOfPages){
            res.redirect('/?page='+encodeURIComponent(numberOfPages));
        }else if(page < 1){
            res.redirect('/?page='+encodeURIComponent('1'));
        }
        //Determine the SQL LIMIT starting number
        const startingLimit = (page - 1) * resultsPerPage;
        //Get the relevant number of POSTS for this starting page
        sql = `SELECT * FROM photos LIMIT ${startingLimit},${resultsPerPage}`;
        db.query(sql, (err, result)=>{
            if(err) throw err;
            let iterator = (page - 5) < 1 ? 1 : page - 5;
            let endingLink = (iterator + 9) <= numberOfPages ? (iterator + 9) : page + (numberOfPages - page);
            if(endingLink < (page + 4)){
                iterator -= (page + 4) - numberOfPages;
            }
            res.render('index', {data: result, page, iterator, endingLink, numberOfPages});
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Is this really your code? I don't understand why you have 2 nested DB queries... What's the value of `sql` when you trigger the first query? Also, why would you need to keep the search query when navigating to another results page? Each navigation should trigger a new DB query and it does not need to know the previous query results

Comment: Thankyou sir for the help. After long thoughts and research I solved it using jquery data tables.